# List all parallel environments of queues of Sun Grid Engine

Tags: sungridengine

I can get a list of all queues on my Sun Grid Engine via

```
qstat -g c
```

So I get something like this

```
CLUSTER QUEUE                   CQLOAD   USED    RES  AVAIL  TOTAL aoACDS  cdsuE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
queue1   .................................................
queue2   .................................................
```

And I can rip the first element (or just tack on `-xml` option and rip out all names) to get a list of available queues.
But every queue has a defined number of parallel environments. For example, `queue1` can have `mpi-long` and `mpi-big` parallel environments specified via `pe` keyword. How can I iterate through queues and get the info on what parallel environments are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, i think:

```
qconf -spl
```

(works for SGE on our cluster)

from: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/820-0698/chp10-6/index.html